# Android Assist API in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello I have a android app that has a activity I want to use the assist API on so when the user holds or swipes on the home button it will open the app

here's my code for my app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace ToolBelt.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ToolBelt")]
    public class ToolBelt : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }

//apps main code 

    }


}
```

here's my Manifest:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.d4a.toolbelt" android:versionName="1.6" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="6">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
        <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name="com.d4a.toolbelt.ToolBelt" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.extra.ASSIST_PACKAGE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

The app works but the assist feature does NOT work any idea why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Android generates a new AndroidManifest.xml file when you build your project. Hence, if you modify that file manually, especially  `<application>` entries, then they will get overwritten and your manual changes disappear.

So if you want to add an `IntentFilter` to your `Activity` you need to do it using the `IntentFilterAttribute` and decorate your `Activity` with it.

The XML can be translated to:

```
[Activity (LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Theme = "@style/Theme.Transparent")]
[IntentFilter(new []{Intent.ActionAssist}, Categories = new []{Intent.CategoryDefault})]
public class AssistActivity : Activity
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply I tried you suggestion and It's still not working  do I replace the "public class ToolBelt : Activity" with "public class AssistActivity : Activity"? Please let me know :)

Comment: Is ToolBelt your own Activity?

Comment: yes it is any ideas why it's not working for me? Thank you for all your help so far!

Comment: Are you applying this to your own Activity?

Comment: Yes I am this is what my activity looks like : namespace ToolBelt.Droid
{
    
    [Activity(MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance, Theme = "@style/Theme.Transparent")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ExtraAssistPackage }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class AssistActivity : ToolBelt
    {
    }
    public class ToolBelt : Activity
    {}

Comment: the theme works great the assist part is the only thing that is still not working thank you for all your help! :)

Comment: I think the problem is that you are responding to the incorrect Intent. According to the documentation the, extra stuff are optional parameters you supply with the Intent. You need to listen to ACTION_ASSIST, which is `Intent.ActionAssist` in Xamarin. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ASSIST

Comment: Thank you so much for the update! I changed  Intent.ExtraAssistPackage  to Intent.ActionAssist and it worked Like a champ Thank you so much your awesome! :)